# DCOM connection is lost due to inactivity

Tags: delphi, dcom

We have a Delphi application running as DCOM server in same network on PCs.

1. Windows 8.1
2. Windows Server 2008

Work scenario

Both servers responds many small task for several hours and after that there are hours of inactivity.

**Issue**:

After long period of inactivity all client of Windows 8.1 machine are disconnected while on Windows Server 2008 are connected.

I've googled and found only network hardware reasons for this type of issue. Our sysadmin excluded it from list.

I wonder is it something that can be configured from registry or better from server application with WINAPI.

Comment: Not what you're asking, I know, but you might want to consider repacking your server as a DataSnap one (DataSnap doesn't have to involve DB access at all).  It avoids all the problems of remote COM activation.

Comment: Have you enabled/configured MSDTC?

Comment: Are you using Windows 8.1 as a *server*?

Comment: @mjn Yes. Hardware of this PC is far better from the rest.

Comment: @PageNotFound No we do not change nothing except Firewall settings and dcomcnfg